# Null pointer when trying to do rewriteBatchedStatements for MySQL and Java

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement, hikaricp, batch-insert

I am trying to do batch inserts into mysql at very high rates.  I wanted to try the rewriteBatchedStatements config option as I have read it can make significantly affect performance.  When I add the option however I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.computeMaxParameterSetSizeAndBatchSize(PreparedStatement.java:1694)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.computeBatchSize(PreparedStatement.java:1651)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchedInserts(PreparedStatement.java:1515)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1272)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.StatementProxy.executeBatch(StatementProxy.java:116)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.PreparedStatementJavassistProxy.executeBatch(PreparedStatementJavassistProxy.java)
```

This is my code that does the inserts:

```
try (Connection connection = DBUtil.getInstance().getConnection();
         PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        for (TransactionBatch batch : batches) {
            try {                   
                preparedStatement.setString(1, batch.getDeviceID());
                preparedStatement.setBinaryStream(2, new ByteArrayInputStream(dataArray));
                preparedStatement.addBatch();
            } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        preparedStatement.executeBatch();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is my jdbc url:

```
jdbc:mysql://url:port/tableName?user=userame&password=password&useServerPrepStmts=false&rewriteBatchedStatements=true
```

Also I am using HikariCP as my connection pool.

EDIT: Update - looks like the problem relates to having a varbinary(10000) column in the table

Comment: I don't think you can rewrite batches containing blob data.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to stop using:

```
preparedStatement.setBinaryStream(inputstream)
```

instead I used

```
preparedStatement.setBytes(byte[])
```

In order to rewrite it must need to calculate the total size which it can't do upfront from an input stream.  It is working great now and my write speeds are awesome!